# Remove all commas in a line after the first comma character and before a fixed string

Tags: regex, csv, unix

Hi I have a csv file with something like this

```
          1000,1000-ABC NAME,TOP NAME,akjdksa
          1001,1001-ABC,EFG NAME,TOP NAME,ldjaskd
          1002,1002-ABC,XYZ NAME,TOP NAME,kljdasd
          1003,1003-ABC,QSG NAME,TOP NAME,lakdj
```

This is a huge file though. What I want to do is remove all commas after the first comma and before the text "TOP NAME" appears on that line. So my output would be something like

```
          1000,1000-ABC NAME,TOP NAME,akjdksa
          1001,1001-ABC EFG NAME,TOP NAME,ldjaskd
          1002,1002-ABC XYZ NAME,TOP NAME,kljdasd
          1003,1003-ABC QSG NAME,TOP NAME,lakdj
```

Any suggestions on how I can do this in Unix?

Comment: Your desired output is identical to your input.

Comment: No its not, from the second row, there is a "space" instead of "comma" after ABC

Comment: Are you familiar with `sed`?

Answer (score 0):

If your string "ABC," is gonna be constant. You can use sed to find "ABC," and replace it with "ABC " globally.
sed 's/ABC,/ABC /g' file.txt